# Find next certain weekday with mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, date, stored-procedures

in my database i have a column 4 cases:

- 1: tuesday
- 2: wednesday
- 3: thursday
- 4: friday

im trying to make a stored procedure that based on the current date finds the next weekday. 
For instance if its wednesday xx.xx.xxxx and case 1, the next tuesday will be yy.yy.yyyy the upcoming week.
Here is the hard catch :) If the wanted weekday is the next day, it should select the date of the next week.

What i have so far:

```
BEGIN
SELECT
    CASE case_number
    WHEN 1 THEN ''
    WHEN 2 THEN ''
    WHEN 3 THEN ''
    WHEN 4 THEN ''
    ELSE 'unknown'
    END
FROM customer
WHERE customer_id = customerId;
END
```

Im looking for the code between ' ' of course :) I know i need to play with DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL x DAY), (i think..) but i cant figure it out! Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DAYOFWEEK(now())
In fact you naad a CASE inside CASE.

depending on the day of week number add appropriate amount of days to now()

```
SELECT
    CASE case_number
    WHEN 1 THEN CASE DAYOFWEEK(now())
                 WHEN 0 THEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL x DAY)
                 WHEN 1 THEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL x DAY)
                 WHEN 2 THEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL x DAY)
    .....
                END
    WHEN 2 THEN ''
    WHEN 3 THEN ''
    WHEN 4 THEN ''
    ELSE 'unknown'
    END
FROM customer
```

Comment: thanks for the input, but i dont understand the second CASE. You find the current day of week and when what are the int parameters?

Comment: day's number DAYOFWEEK *Returns the weekday index for date (1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, …, 7 = Saturday)*

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below query works, you can modify the WHERE condition to include other days as well

Example : case_number>=0 AND case_number<7 (0 - Monday .... 6 - Sunday)

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) <= case_number THEN
              DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL (7 + (case_number - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()))) DAY)
         ELSE
              DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL (7 - (WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) - case_number)) DAY)
    END
FROM customer WHERE case_number>= 1 AND case_number <= 4
```